# how to check all reachable cells from one cell

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, merge, cell

I need to check all possible paths that is reachable from one certain cell in a 2d array. For example;

```
int [][] grid = {{2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}, 
                 {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1}, 
                 {1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2}, 
                 {8, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2}, 
                 {1, 2, 5, 0, 3, 3}, 
                 {5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0}};`
```

and I want to check all cells that is reachable from cell(2)(1) (it is just an example location). First some number will be placed here if this location is zero. For example, 1 is placed at that location.
Then I need to start merging all 1’s which are reachable from cell (2,1).Then cell(2)(1) location must be replaced with the 2 if the cells that create this path includes at least two 1 since 1+1 = 2.
  After that, the cells which are used during merging process must be assigned to zero. 
But if there is still possible merging for cell(2)(1) they should be merged too.
I try to use recursive function but it did not work as I want.
I could not figure out how to prevent merging if there are less than 3 neighbor cells which includes same value and how to merge until no possible merging left. Method should continue merging until there are no possible merge left, but my code merge for once. I have just started to learn java sorry for mistakes already now.

Comment: Two important concepts that you should search on the web and then memorize their usage: breadth-first-search (plus depth-first-search) and adjaceny matrices. Two different concepts that are both very useful.

Comment: I will check them too as soon as possible. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So...
I am not sure if I got everything right because some things are misleading.
cell(2)(2) has the initial content: 2

I think your chosen cell is (1)(2).  //note: indices in java start with 0

So your idea is a little bit more complex and should not be solved with only one method.

I've written some code:

```
private static int[][] directions = new int[][]{{1,0},{-1,0},{0,1},{0,-1}};

public static void step(int[][] array, int x, int y) {

     if(array[x][y] == 0){
         array[x][y] = 1;
     }else{
         return;
     }
    int number = 1;
    while(true){
        printGrid(array);
        int amount = process(array, x, y);
        if(amount == 1)break;
        number ++;
        array[x][y] = number;
    }
}

public static int process(int[][] array,int x, int y){
    int number = array[x][y];
    if(number == 0) return 0;
    int total = 1;
    array[x][y] = 0;
    for(int[] dire:directions){
        if(x + dire[0] >= 0 && x + dire[0] < array.length && y + dire[1] >= 0 && y + dire[1] < array[0].length){
            if(array[x + dire[0]][y+dire[1]] == number){
                total += process(array, x + dire[0], y+dire[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}


public static void printGrid(int[][] grid) {
    for(int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
        String s = "";
        for(int n = 0; n<  grid[0].length; n++){
            s += grid[i][n]+", ";
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int [][] grid =
            {{2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2},
            {1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2},
            {8, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2},
            {1, 2, 5, 0, 3, 3},
            {5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0}};

    Main.step(grid, 2,1);

   printGrid(grid);
```

### }

I modified it like this;

```
public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game Merge Numbers. Your grid as follows:");
    int[][] newGrid = {{2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 8}, 
                      {2, 1, 0, 2, 4, 0}, 
                      {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3}, 
                      {2, 3, 2,0, 1, 0}, 
                      {0, 0, 5, 8, 7, 2}, 
                      {2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
    for(int i = 0 ; i < newGrid.length ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < newGrid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(newGrid[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    try (Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in)){
    System.out.print("Please enter your target's row index:");
    int newRow = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter your target's column index:");
    int newColumn = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter the number that you want to add to location " + newRow +  " " +  newColumn);
    int newNextNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
    step(newGrid, newRow, newColumn, newNextNumber);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < newGrid.length ; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < newGrid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(newGrid[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }}
}

public static void step(int[][] grid, int row, int column, int nextNumber ) {

     if(grid[row][column] == 0){
         grid[row][column] = nextNumber;
     }else{
         return;
     }
     int number = nextNumber;
    while(true){
        int amount = process(grid, row, column);
        if(amount == 1)break;
        number ++;
        grid[row][column] = number;
    }
}

public static int process(int[][] grid,int row, int column){
    int number = grid[row][column];
    if(number == 0) return 0;
    int total = 1;
    grid[row][column] = 0;
    for(int[] dire:directions){
        if(row + dire[0] >= 0 && row + dire[0] < grid.length && column + dire[1] >= 0 && column + dire[1] < grid[0].length){
            if(grid[row + dire[0]][column+dire[1]] == number){
                total += process(grid, row + dire[0], column+dire[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

}
But when I run it all the points include the target location becomes zero. Output is like;

```
Welcome to the game Merge Numbers. Your grid as follows:
2 0 1 1 0 8 
2 1 0 2 4 0 
1 2 1 2 1 3 
2 3 2 0 1 0 
0 0 5 8 7 2 
2 0 1 1 0 0 
Please enter your target's row index:3
Please enter your target's column index:3
Please enter the number that you want to add to location 3 3: 1
2 0 1 1 0 8 
2 1 0 0 4 0 
1 2 1 0 0 3 
2 3 0 0 0 0 
0 0 5 8 7 2 
2 0 1 1 0 0
```

I mean if you look at the first grid in the output, cell(3)(3) is zero. When 1 is placed here, the 1's that are reachable from this cell(3)(3) merged. Then cell(3)(3) includes 2. After that same procedure follows. But when all possible merges done, all cells that has been used during the process include center became 0. Center should be increase by one after each merging. I think, I use the fourth parameter which is nextNumber incorrectly. Should function process also include that parameter or not? Sorry to disturb you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can find neighbors of a cell...

```
int x[] = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, +1, +1, +1}; 
int y[] = {-1, 0, +1, -1, +1, -1, 0, +1};
// looping through the neghibours...
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    if( p+x[i] < n && q+y[i] < m && a[p + x[i]][q + y[i]] == a[p][q]) {
        // neighbour
    }
}
```

Here is the recursive implementation of your problem, `n` & `m` is the size of grid `a` and `p` & `q` is the index of the cell you want to perform merge...

```
public static void merge(int a[][], int n, int m, int p, int q) {

    int x[] = {-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, +1, +1, +1};
    int y[] = {-1, 0, +1, -1, +1, -1, 0, +1};
    int c = 0;
    // looping through the neghibours...
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if( p+x[i] < n && q+y[i] < m && a[p + x[i]][q + y[i]] == a[p][q]) {
            c++;
        }
    }

    if(c > 3) { // merging only if neghibours > 3
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            if( p+x[i] < n && q+y[i] < m && a[p + x[i]][q + y[i]] == a[p][q]) {
                a[p + x[i]][q + y[i]] = 0;
            }
        }
        a[p][q] += 1;
        merge(a, n, m, p, q); // recurcively merging if possible...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. Thank you so much. I think my problem was that I could not use loop inside the method. I tried but it is hard to use loop inside a recursive function.